# Find the values of α and β for which this series converges.

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

The given series is,

$$\sum\limits_{n\geq 1}(\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n})^{\alpha}(\ln(1+1/n))^{\beta}$$

With $\alpha, \beta \in \mathbb{R}$.

I don't know how to begin, noreven which criterion use to find the values of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ for which this series converges.

Comment: it's like $\sum 1/n^{\alpha/2 +\beta }$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you multiply the first term by $\frac{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}}$ and use Maclauring series expansion for the second term, you can compare the sum to
$$
\frac{1}{2^{\alpha}}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^{\frac{\alpha}{2}+\beta}}
$$
which converges for $\frac{\alpha}{2}{+\beta}>1$